# How to use Wcf web service in MVC using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have use wcf web service for data connectivity and all data related operation.
So, In my application, i need to integrate MVC controller pass or get model using the WCF webservice.

Please help how to pass model to WCF webservice from controller and How to get that Model or list of items into Controller ???

Comment: Do you know how to call a WCF service?  Calling it from a controllor is no different - a controller is just code.

Comment: Please send any example for this .....

Comment: There are many examples all over - search for "call wcf service."

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to pass your actual controller to the WCF service. You don't want to couple your view tightly with the data contract of an external service.

Create a separate ViewModel that fulfills the needs of the view. Then implement code in the ViewModel to call the web service to update data and a static factory method on the ViewModel that creates a new ViewModel instance by retrieving data from the web service and populating a  ViewModel instance.